# Prove that $2AB$ is square

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $$A= 1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3! \cdots 1002!$$ 
$$B= 1004!\cdot 1005! \cdots 2006!$$

Prove that $2AB$ is square. Help guys, I tried, I really did but I couldn't.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $$\begin{align}
1! \times 2! &= 2 \times (1!)^2 \times 1,\\
3! \times 4! &=  2 \times (3!)^2 \times 2,\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
1004! &= 2 \times (1003)! \times 502\\
1005! \times 1006! &= 2 \times (1005!)^2 \times 503\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
2005! \times 2006! &= 2 \times (2005!)^2 \times 1003
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

With help from above comment we have: 
\begin{align}
2AB &= 2(1!×2!×...×1002!)(1004!×1005!×...×2006!) \\
&= 2(2^{501}×1×2×...×501)(2^{500}×502×503×...×1003)((1!)^2(2!)^2 ...(1003!)×(1005!)^2 ...(2005!)^2 \\
&= 2^{1002}(1!)^2 ...(1003!)(1003!)(1005!)^2 (1006)^2 ...(2005)^2 \\
&=  2^{1002} ...
\end{align}
square.